# XPointer URL not resolved when addressing apostrophe-encased @id values

Tags: xml, xpath, xpointer

Frustrating issue with XInclude / XPointer here.

The aim is to include entries from a list of XML-formatted price-entries into another document.
I have a document with a list of prices that looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <!DOCTYPE preise [
   <!ELEMENT preise (preis+)>
   <!ELEMENT preis (#PCDATA)>
   <!ATTLIST preis id ID #REQUIRED>
 ]>
 <preise>
   <preis id="a0">./.</preis>
 <preis id='foo100'>136,10</preis>
 <preis id='foo101'>163,32</preis>
 </preise>
```

The following include fails

```
 <xi:include href="../listen/preise.xml#xpointer(/preise/preis[@id='foo100']/text())" />
```

with

```
 element include: XInclude error : failed build URL
```

Now if I change the format of the ids in the price-list to be exclusively numerical

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <!DOCTYPE preise [
   <!ELEMENT preise (preis+)>
   <!ELEMENT preis (#PCDATA)>
   <!ATTLIST preis id ID #REQUIRED>
 ]>
 <preise>
   <preis id="a0">./.</preis>
 <preis id='100'>136,10</preis>
 <preis id='101'>163,32</preis>
 </preise>
```

and use this include without the apostrophes

```
 <xi:include href="../listen/preise.xml#xpointer(/preise/preis[@id=100]/text())" />
```

suddenly everything works.
So the issue seems to be related to the apostrophes, but how do I get around that?

Also, here's my xmllint version info:

```
 xmllint: using libxml version 20706
    compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and proposed solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From the [XInclude W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/#include_element)**:

> The xi:include element has the
>   following attributes:
>
> href
>
> A value which, after appropriate
>   escaping (see 4.1.1 Escaping of href
>   attribute values) has been performed,
>   results in a URI reference or an IRI
>   reference specifying the location of
>   the resource to include. The href
>   attribute is optional; the absence of
>   this attribute is the same as
>   specifying href="", that is, the
>   reference is to the same document. If
>   the href attribute is absent when
>   parse="xml", the xpointer attribute
>   must be present. **Fragment
>   identifiers must not be used; their
>   appearance is a fatal error.** A value
>   that results in a syntactically
>   invalid URI or IRI should be reported
>   as a fatal error, but some
>   implementations may find it
>   impractical to distinguish this case
>   from a resource error.

So, "**Fragment identifiers must not be used; their appearance is a fatal error.**"

**Solution**: Try to omit the `href` attribute and to use the `xpointer` attribute.

**However**, be aware of the **[following text](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/#application)** from the same spec:

> Support for the [XPointer xpointer() Scheme] is not mandatory for full XInclude conformance. 
>   Authors are advised that use of xpointer() and other XPointer schemes than element() might not be 
>   supported by all conformant XInclude implementations

Finally, **[here is an example from the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/#fragment-example)** of using XPointer fragment inclusion:

> The following illustrates the results of including fragments of another XML document. Assume the 
>   base URI of the document is http://www.example.com/JoeSmithQuote.xml.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<price-quote xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <prepared-for>Joe Smith</prepared-for>
  <good-through>20040930</good-through>
  <xi:include href="price-list.xml" xpointer="w002-description"/>
  <volume>40</volume>
  <xi:include href="price-list.xml" xpointer="element(w002-prices/2)"/>
</price-quote>
```

> price-list.xml references a DTD which declares the id attributes as type ID, and contains:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE price-list SYSTEM "price-list.dtd">
<price-list xml:lang="en-us">
  <item id="w001">
    <description id="w001-description">
      <p>Normal Widget</p>
    </description>
    <prices id="w001-prices">
      <price currency="USD" volume="1+">39.95</price>
      <price currency="USD" volume="10+">34.95</price>
      <price currency="USD" volume="100+">29.95</price>
    </prices>
  </item>
  <item id="w002">
    <description id="w002-description">
      <p>Super-sized widget with bells <i>and</i> whistles.</p>
    </description>
    <prices id="w002-prices">
      <price currency="USD" volume="1+">59.95</price>
      <price currency="USD" volume="10+">54.95</price>
      <price currency="USD" volume="100+">49.95</price>
    </prices>
  </item>
</price-list>
```

> The infoset resulting from resolving inclusions on this document is the same (except for the 
>   include history and language properties) as that of the following document:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<price-quote xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <prepared-for>Joe Smith</prepared-for>
  <good-through>20040930</good-through>
  <description id="w002-description" xml:lang="en-us"
               xml:base="http://www.example.com/price-list.xml">
    <p>Super-sized widget with bells <i>and</i> whistles.</p>
  </description>
  <volume>40</volume>
  <price currency="USD" volume="10+" xml:lang="en-us"
         xml:base="http://www.example.com/price-list.xml">54.95</price>
</price-quote>
```

Comment: This answer definitely deserves more than a +1